# How to configure a linux machine so it never freezes?

Tags: linux, freeze, resource-usage

Occasionally my machine is out of memory busy swapping or whatnot, and during that time it is not responsive (frozen) and the only way to regain control is by manually invoking the OOM killer with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Is there a way to configure a linux machine such that a non-system app could never "take down" the entire system? Specifically I would like the mouse and window manager to always be responsive.

For example, maybe reserve resources for system processes?

Comment: This may have more to do with what you are running than the operating system. You can overrun Mac, Linux and Windows and cause them to freeze for a period of time. Take a look at the load you are applying. Also try a server model of Linux where you can have more control over the load impact.

Comment: @John Ideally it shouldn't matter what I'm running - the operating system should be able to not freeze.

Answer (score 1):

### Disable overcommit

Typically, the [overcommit](https://lwn.net/Articles/317814/) value `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` is set to zero, which allows processes to "allocate" more memory than physically available to the system.

```
# temporarily
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio

# permanently - /etc/sysctl.conf
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 0
```

but some apps may fail to start.

### Permanently adjust service's OOM score

With systemd, to protect services from being OOM-killed, edit the service file ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299332))

```
systemctl edit syslog.service
```

and set [OOMScoreAdjust](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#OOMScoreAdjust=) to -1000

```
[Service]
OOMScoreAdjust=-1000
```

Conversely, to mark services as sacrifical lamb for OOM-kill, set the value to 1000.